# Aiflow Branch issue

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-taskflow

There're 4 task to run, and a condition filier

I expect that happen:

1. if `t0` return `True`, skip `t1`, run `t2` then `t3`
2. if `t0` return `False`, run `t1`, but when `t1` done, run `t2` then `t3`

logic like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdU3H.png)

but why does flow also skip t2, t3 when t1 skiped?

flow.py file

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator, BranchPythonOperator
from datetime import datetime

def f0():
    print("this is function0")
    return False
    # return Ture

def f1():
    print("this is function1")

def f2():
    print("this is function2")

def f3():
    print("this is function3")

def branch_chooser(**kwargs):
    return 't2' if kwargs['ti'].xcom_pull(task_ids='t0') else 't1'

with DAG(
    'TEST',
    default_args={
        'depends_on_past': False,
        'retries': 1,
    },
    description='test process',
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=datetime(2023, 1, 1),
    catchup=False,
) as dag:
    t0 = PythonOperator(
        task_id='t0',
        python_callable=f0,
        provide_context=True,
        dag=dag,
    )

    branch_task = BranchPythonOperator(
        task_id='Branch_condition',
        python_callable=branch_chooser,
        provide_context=True,
        dag=dag,
    )

    t1 = PythonOperator(
        task_id='t1',
        python_callable=f1,
        dag=dag,
    )

    t2 = PythonOperator(
        task_id='t2',
        python_callable=f2,
        dag=dag,
    )

    t3 = PythonOperator(
        task_id='t3',
        python_callable=f3,
        dag=dag,
    )

    # Set up the DAG with two distinct paths
    t0 >> branch_task
    branch_task >> t1
    branch_task >> t2
    t1 >> t2
    t2 >> t3
```

Try many combonation, can't get what I expect.

Answer (score 1):

It's simpler than you think:

```
def branch_chooser(**kwargs):
    return None if kwargs['ti'].xcom_pull(task_ids='t0') else 't1'

with DAG(...):
    ...

    t2 = PythonOperator(
        task_id='t2',
        python_callable=f2,
        trigger_rule='none_failed'  # << important!
        dag=dag,
    )

    # Keep it simple!
    t0 >> branch_task >> t1 >> t2 >> t3
```

With `branch_task` we only decide to run t1 or not. If it runs, t2 and t3 run sequentially as usual. If not (`branch_chooser` returned `None`), t1 is skipped.

Now say hello to [trigger rules](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/dags.html#trigger-rules). With default setting of `all_success` t2 runs only if it's predecessor t1 finished successfully. If it skipped, t2 and all downstream tasks will skip as well.

However with `trigger_rule='none_failed'` it's enough that t1 hasn't failed - skipped is fine and t2 runs normally, followed by t3.